# Is Patheon's 100% crit calculated on cast, or when his attack lands?

Tags: league-of-legends

If a Patheon throws his spear at Kennen at 5% hp, but before the spear lands Kennen gets healed, does that spear still have a 100% crit?

Answer (score 1):

I think it's applied when the spear hits, with the knowledge that other skills (Teemo shrooms, Cait ult, etc) have their damage calculated when they actually hit.

Answer (score 1):

The damage is calculated when it hits because of spell shields and other damage mitigation methods. The same goes for all abilities.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure, but im quiete sure that Pantheons spear cant crit since it doesnt apply on hit effects. But if he melee hit him before soraka heals then yes, it will crits.

Comment: It isn't a "real" crit, but HSS has a passive that lets Panth's skills do double damage on dudes below fifteen (I think) percent health.

Comment: @Huggernaut as far as I know, only AAs and Spear receive the HSS passive.